# Android: custom seekbar thumb doesn't show correctly

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a custom SeekBar with a specific style:

```
      <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/mediacontroller_progress"
            style="@style/MediaSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

MediaSeekBar style:

```
    <style name="MediaSeekBar" parent="android:Widget.SeekBar">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/media_seek_bar</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxHeight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/media_seek_bar_thumb</item>
        <item name="android:progress">0</item>
    </style>
```

media_seek_bar drawable:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="0dip" />
            <solid android:color="#20ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="0dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="0dip" />
                <solid android:color="@color/theme_accent_1" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

media_seek_bar_thumb drawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/control_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/control_pressed" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/control_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/control_normal" />
</selector>
```

And the result:

*without press*

[image]

*when I press thumb*
[image]

So the problem is the area arround the yellow circle: it's translucent in my png files but not in App.

Comment: The area around the circle or the circle itself?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your images inside selector. Probably images have extra space. I have tried to run your code with custom drawable inside selector and it works fine. Here my circle drawable:

`<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#ffe600"/>
    <size
        android:width="15dp"
        android:height="15dp"/>
 </shape>`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<SeekBar
    android:splitTrack="false"
    ....
/>
```

Will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

just set this code and work

```
android:thumbTint="@android:color/transparent" // this code for hide thumb
android:splitTrack="false" // this code for show correctly
```